# Node names getting disappeared after dragging complete graph in tree layout on edge browser

Tags: d3.js

I have created tree using D3.js. Node names getting disappeared after dragging complete graph in tree layout on Microsoft edge browser of windows 10.

Comment: Code is added in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oo66o0q0/6/  Please check this code

Comment: Any solution to this issue?